# Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function sendEmail() {
var eradio = $('#eradio').val();
var ename = $('#ename').val();
var ephone = $('#ephone').val();
var eemail = $('#eemail').val();

if (ename!='' && email!='') {
    if (isEmpty(cart)) {
        $.post(
            "core/mail.php",
            {
                "ename" : ename,
                "eradio" : eradio,
                "ephone" : ephone,
                "eemail" : eemail,
                "ecomment" : ecomment,
                "cart" : cart
            },
            function(data){
                if (data==1) {
                    alert ('Заказ отправлен');

                }
                else {
                    alert('Повторите заказ');
                }
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        alert('Корзина пуста');
    }
}
else {
    alert('Заполните поля');
}
```

}

в консоли ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at e (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4)
at Vc (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4)
at Vc (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4)
at Vc (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4)
at Function.m.param (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4)
at Function.m.(anonymous function) [as post] (http://dosliderstroy.ru/seitron/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:22515)
at HTMLInputElement.sendEmail (cart.js:108)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
```

Ошибку показывает на строке  $.post(

Comment: подключи не минифицированный jQuery и посмотри что изменится в stacktrace

Comment: Что это или где это найти?

Comment: Я про ошибку в консоли: то что ты привел в вопросе - это текст ошибки `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` а далее stacktrace.

Comment: Так как используется минифицированная версия jquery (jquery-1.11.2.min.js) в ней проблематично разбираться. Обычно подключение не минифицированной версии облегчает поиск ошибки

Comment: как подключить не минифицированную версию?

Comment: вместо `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` использовать `jquery-1.11.2.js`

Comment: добавил: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
Не минифицированный файл подключил, ошибки теже

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at add (jquery-1.12.4.js:10073)
    at buildParams (jquery-1.12.4.js:10061)
    at buildParams (jquery-1.12.4.js:10055)
    at buildParams (jquery-1.12.4.js:10055)
    at Function.jQuery.param (jquery-1.12.4.js:10095)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-1.12.4.js:9612)
    at Function.jQuery.(anonymous function) [as post] (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:9890:17)
    at HTMLInputElement.sendEmail (cart.js:108)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)

Comment: добавь этот вывод в вопрос. А так же добавь в вопрос значения переменных `ename`, `eradio`,`ephone`,`eemail`,`ecomment`,`cart`

Comment: Проблема в одной из двух переменных `ecomment` или `cart` - хотя бы одна из них, похоже, является dom элементом. Из-за этого и происходит ошибка

Comment: Проблема была в ecomment

Comment: Добавь ответ, с описанием проблемы и как решил.

Comment: Просто стёр весь код и заново написал тоже самое, а если быть точнее Стёр строку "ecomment" : ecomment, и чуть выше записал её